# change the position of my div container based on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am actually styling my app. I have container between my header and footer, when i scroll the page, when the container meets the header i want  the position changed to fixed from relative.

Initial setting :

```
.div {
        position: relative;
        zoom: 1;
        z-index: auto;
  }
```

once the div container is new the header i want the position of the div changed to fixed .

```
.div {
        position: fixed;
        zoom: 1;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        left: 400px;
    }
```

how do i achieve this? can any help me.

thank you.

Comment: "when the container meets the header" - what does that mean? "once the div container is new the header" - what does that mean? And where's your markup?

Comment: My header is fixed. when i scroll up, my div container also scrolls up and when it  is about to meet the bottom part of my header. i want the position of the div container to be changed to fixed.

Comment: Now I understand your question, and I updated my answer, please check it

Answer (score 0):

Use `onscroll` for your container:

```
<div class="div" id="content" onscroll="onScroll()">
...
<div id="container"></div>
...
</div>
```

You have to use javascript and check if the container meets the header or not:

```
function onScroll() {
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var scrollTop = content.scrollTop;
    var elOffsetTop = container.offsetTop;
    var elHeight = container.offsetHeight;
    if ((scrollTop > elOffsetTop)&&(scrollTop<elOffsetTop+elHeight)) {
      content.classList.add("on-top");
    } else {
      content.classList.remove("on-top");
    }
  }
```

And in css:

```
.on-top {
  position: fixed;
  ...
}
```

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/en7Lf2wz/6/